# List returning empty after putting it through removeEven function in other file

Tags: python, list, function

sorry about the code it is sloppy right now because I've been trying to fix it. Im using a function from another file to remove even numbers from my list but after I call the function the list returns empty.

```
from usefullFunctions import *
def main ():
    mylist1 = uRandomList(10,0,15)
    listLength = len(mylist1)
    print("list1 contains %s numbers " % listLength)
    print (mylist1)
    evenOut = removeEven(mylist1)
    print (mylist1)


main()
```

These are the two functions that I am calling from the other file.

```
def removeEven(listIn):
    result = []
    i = 0 
    while i < len(listIn):
        if (i % 2 ) == 0:
            listIn.pop(i)
        else:
            i = i + 1 
    return result
```

```
def uRandomList (num, minValue, maxValue):
    result = []
    for i in range (num):
        d1 = randint(minValue, maxValue)
        if d1 not in result:
            result.append(d1)
    return result
```

I'm just trying to get it to remove even numbers from the list so that I can print it with the even numbers removed.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Fixed function

```
def removeEven(listIn):
    i = 0 
    while i < len(listIn):
        if listIn[i] % 2  == 0:
            listIn.pop(i)
        else:
            i = i + 1 
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my eyes, its that you're declaring a list here, `result = []`, then returning it `return result` without actually doing anything to it in between. So you've created an empty list, then returned it.

```
def removeEven(listIn):
    result = [] # first mention of "result"
    i = 0 
    while i < len(listIn):
        if (i % 2 ) == 0:
            listIn.pop(i)
        else:
            i = i + 1 
    return result # only other reference
```

Although the error here is pretty straightforward, I think maybe you have some misunderstandings about lists in Python. It could help to think about

- Is the "removeEven" function supposed to modify the existing list? or is it supposed to return a new one? You're doing both here, which is likely not the best solution. calling `listIn.pop()` is modifying the original list being passed, but you've created a *new* list to be returned, and you've also created a new variable for it in your original file

In my opinion it might be more appropriate to return a new list in this case, so that's what i'll show you here

```
def with_even_removed(list_in):
    result = []

    i = 0
    while i < len(list_in):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            result.append(list_in[i])
        i += 1
    return result


l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

l2 = with_even_removed(l)

print("original list =", l)
print("newly returned list =", l2)
```

Output

```
original list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
newly returned list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

As you can see, the original list `l` was unchanged, but the returned list `l2` is different, it has the even index numbers removed

Comment: So removing the creation of result and only using return will modify the original list and return the value to the original list? So `def removeEven(listIn):
    i = 0 
    while i < len(listIn):
        if (i % 2 ) == 0:
            listIn.pop(i)
        else:
            i = i + 1 
    return`

Comment: Sorry, that looks pretty bad I don't know how to make it look better in comments.

Comment: The modifying of the original list is happening when you call "pop()", that method will remove something from the list you called it on. I've updated the answer here with some example code for you to try, I think this will help you with your problem. If it works for you, I'd appreciate it if you marked this as the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you, what you posted worked but I am still wondering why what I had originally didn't. Why does pop not work and returns a blank list when append does work and returns a correct list?

Comment: pop does work, but not the way you were using it. pop will remove an element from a list.  So I'll describe what your original method did. 1. Take a list as an input. 2. Create a new empty list. 3. Remove all the even elements from the input list. 4. Return the new empty list that was created in step 2.  So they way you used it in your question, `myList1` would have its elements popped, then `evenOut` would be an empty list

Comment: Thank you for you answer I updated my original post with the working function at the bottom of the post if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing `i` in `if` block of `removeEven()`. So, say input list has 3 elements. When `i` is 0 initially, you remove element 0. `len(listIn)` becomes 2. In next iteration `i` is still 0 and you remove the first element again. This process continues and remove all elements from input list. The idea to loop until length of the input list while the loop is removing element from that list is not good. Also the function is returning an empty list.

As I can see, you are returning another list from `removeEven()`. So why not leave the input list as it is. Use something like -

```
def removeEven(listIn):
    return [v for index, val in enumerate(listIn) if index % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a function that returns 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers:

```
is_odd = lambda x: x % 2
```

Then pass that function into a list comprehension using the result from `uRandomList`:

```
odd_nums = [x for x in result if is_odd(x)]
```

Edit: While it is entirely possible to shorten this code by just putting the odd/even test inside the list comprehension, it's nice to practice passing functions about as you might have more complicated tests to do at some point.